# Email bouces to tell me it was delivered?

Tags: email, email-bounces

I get this back after sending an email. It says "Your message was successfully delivered", then why do I even get this? Or this phrase referes to something else?

```
Reporting-MTA: dns; gmmr6.centrum.cz
X-Postfix-Queue-ID: CDBBB8016CE1
X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822; [SENDER_EMAIL]
Arrival-Date: Sat, 5 Mar 2011 22:04:41 +0100 (CET)

Final-Recipient: rfc822; [RECIPIENT_EMAIL]
Original-Recipient: rfc822;[RECIPIENT_EMAIL]
Action: delivered
Status: 2.0.0
Diagnostic-Code: X-Postfix; delivery via maildaemon: OK

This is the mail system at host gmmr6.centrum.cz.

Your message was successfully delivered to the destination(s)
listed below. If the message was delivered to mailbox you will
receive no further notifications. Otherwise you may still receive
notifications of mail delivery errors from other systems.

The mail system

<[RECIPIENT_EMAIL]>;: delivery via maildaemon: OK
```

Comment: Is this your mail server, or the recipients? If it's not yours, I don't think there's much you can do (apart from a client side rule to delete these messages).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a Delivery Status Notification - same as for failures, only for successes.  [RFC 1891](http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1891.txt) defines the extensions to SMTP that allow this.

It could be coming from two places: Your mail client is requesting it, or the remote server is configured to always generate a DSN.
In the former case, reconfigure your mail client to eliminate the request for delivery notifications.  In the latter either ask the remote site admin to stop generating  useless emails or do what Ben suggested in his comment: Write a client-side rule to delete them.